# What does a "cooking fire" do?

Tags: melvor-idle

> [image: Yew Cooking Fire---Level 60 Firemaking Required (Wood) 300K (Coin) 500]

In [Melvor Idle](https://melvoridle.com/), I've upgraded my cooking fire, but I'm not sure what it does (if anything).  I think it gives an XP bonus, but the Firemaking page says:

> Bonfire Status: Inactive
>   XP Bonus when active: 0%

**Question**: What does a "cooking fire" do?

Comment: ...I would assume, cook food.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  It improves the Cooking XP (not Firemaking).  Oops... I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this myself, so as to not leave the question unanswered...

Under the Cooking tab, you can see there is a bonus to cooking XP:

[image: Fire Status: Active; Current Fire: Mahogany; XP Bonus: +25%]